# Make fork execute equal amounts of times, infinitely

Tags: c, unix, ipc

I am trying to make the following code never allow the amount of + to be greater than the amounts of - . I am thinking about adding a simple line of just `c sleep(1)` but I was curious to see if there is a better way to make the amounts equal. This is supposed to stay an infinite loop.

```c
int main(){
 if(fork() ==0)
    while(1){
       write(1,"-",1)
   }

  else
     while(1){

       write(1, "+",1);
   }

return 0;
}
```

Would this function correctly using semaphores?

```c
int main(){

int parent_sem = get_semaphore(0);
int child_sem = get_semaphore(1);

 if(fork() ==0)
    while(1){
        sem_wait(child_sem);
       write(1,"-",1);
       sem_signal(parent_sem);
   }

  else
     while(1){
       sem_wait(parent_sem);
       write(1, "+",1);
       sem_signal(child_sem);
   }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want IPC. You could e.g. use a semaphores so that they take it in turns to write a character, but Linux has lots of options so there are probably better ways.

Comment: Yeah, it's going to be way more complicated than that lol. You need to synchronize your processes, because they need to know the state of each other.

Comment: What would be an example of using a semaphore?

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/semaphore.h.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of your semaphore example. I have allocated shared memory so that the semaphores can be accessed by both processes across the fork (I forgot this was necessary, sorry) and fixed the semaphore types and calls.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {
    // Create shared memory for two semaphores
    sem_t* sem = mmap(NULL, 2 * sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                      MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    // Initialise parent and child semaphores: parent = 1, child = 0
    sem_t* parent_sem = sem;
    sem_t* child_sem = sem + 1;    
    sem_init(parent_sem, 1, 1);
    sem_init(child_sem, 1, 0);

    if (fork() == 0) {
        while(1) {
            // Child process
            sem_wait(child_sem);
            write(1, "-", 1);
            sem_post(parent_sem);
        }
    } else {
        while(1) {
            // Parent process
            sem_wait(parent_sem);
            write(1, "+", 1);
            sem_post(child_sem);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is close (Use signals):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void usr1handler() {
}

int main(void) {
        int pid;

        signal(SIGUSR1, usr1handler);

        if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
                while (1) {
                        pause();
                        write(1, "-", 1);
                        fflush(stdout);
                        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
                }
        }
        else {

                sleep(1);

                while (1) {
                        write(1, "+", 1);
                        fflush(stdout);
                        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
                        pause();
                }
        }

}
```

The main issue for this is the race condition. If a process makes it to the kill() function before the other makes it to the pause(), the program freezes. This is probably good enough to start you off though. I left a single sleep in there so you could see that it does indeed print evenly.

Comment: Why are you mixing file descriptors (`write`) and stdio handles (`fflush(stdout)`)?